# How can encode video with images like these (overlay a video over a fixed image) with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, animation, recommendation, animation-rendering

[image: **enter image description here**]

How can encode video with images like these help me ffmpeg ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to know how to stack multiple images horizontally and then overlay another image on top?

Comment: video located at the center of an image please help me how to be able to do

Answer (score 6):

To overlay a half-sized version of a video in the center of an image, use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -i video
-filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2:-1[ovrl];
                 [0][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[v]"
-map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

---

To frame the video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -i video loop 1 -i frame
-filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/2:-1[ovrl];
                 [2][ovrl]scale2ref=iw*1.2:-1[fr][ol];
                 [fr][ol]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[fv];
                 [0][fv]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1[v]"
-map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

If you composite the frame onto the background image beforehand, in ffmpeg or elsewhere, you can just use that resultant image with the first command. Of course, you'll lose freedom of movement for the video overlay.

Comment: error output video without sound

Comment: corrected audio mapping